# How can I change the size of the selected text from a NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c

I have a NSTextView and I'm trying to create a simple text editor. My text view can have several different fonts. If the selected text from the textview has, for instance, two different fonts, how can I change just the size of the selected text?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `textViewDidChangeSelection:` UITextViewDelegate callback when text within your textView is selected and change it's attributes based on the selected range.  Here's an example of changing the selected text to systemFont 25pt greenColor:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.defaultAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]};
}

- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        // set the entire text view to the default attributes initially (in case previously selected text had it's attributes changed)
        [[textView textStorage] setAttributes:self.defaultAttributes range:NSMakeRange(0, textView.attributedText.length)];
        // now set our selected text to the desired attributes
        NSDictionary <NSAttributedStringKey, id> *selectedAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor]};
        [[textView textStorage] setAttributes:selectedAttributes range:textView.selectedRange];
    }];
}
```

you'll obviously need to make this view controller your textView's delegate

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618620-textviewdidchangeselection?language=objc

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  I'd been looking to see how to change a selected range of attributes within a UITextView when the selection is changed by the user while not changing the user's selected range.  I didn't realise that the textStorage could be used to do this.